# How to solve a simple minimax problem?

Tags: optimization, maxima-minima

> $$x=[x_1,x_2];\ y=[y_1,y_2]$$
>   $$f=\left(\frac{x_2}{x_2+y_2}\right)^2\sqrt{\frac{x_1}{x_1+y_1}}$$
>   Find a point where $y$ is at a maximum and $x$ is at a minimum.

This problem is very simple but I cannot remember the exact way to solve it? Thanks a lot :)

Comment: I don't understand the question. It does not make much sens to find the maximum of $y$ or minimum of $x$ since they are in $\mathbb{R}^2$ Do you want the minimum and maximum of $f$ ?

Comment: Actually, the constraints should be 0<=x1,x2<=1 and 0<=x1+x2<=1; 0<=y1,y2<=1 and 0<=y1+y2<=1.